# How can I migrate my existent sqlite db to postgres on heroku?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite, heroku

I deployed my django app on heroku and I can't see my database on the site(users, posts..). If i create a new superuser(couldn't log in with my old superuser so I had to create another one) or any other user, content disappears after some time..
Correct me if I'm wrong I thought heroku converts that for me automatically when I deploy my app, anything I missed? And I did migrate from the heroku CLI
Link: https://network50web.herokuapp.com

Setting:

```
import os
import django_heroku
from decouple import config
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = secretkey

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["network50web.herokuapp.com"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'crispy_forms',
    'network',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'import_export'
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project4.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': (BASE_DIR, 'network/templates'),
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project4.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')
    }
}

import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'network/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (BASE_DIR, 'network/static')

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressManifestStaticFilesStorage'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

IMPORT_EXPORT_USE_TRANSACTIONS = True

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.AutoField'

LOGIN_URL = '/login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Comment: sqlite doesn't work on heroku.  See the answers to the linked duplicate for more details.

Comment: Make Sure you have the `requirements.txt` file along with `.gitignore`. For further details follow this tutorial on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6DI_7Zja8Zc&t=1471s